# SQL ORACLE Problems with three queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables `orders`, `orderdetails` and `customers`.

The `orders` table has these columns:

```
ORDERID, CUSTOMERID, EMPLOYEEID, TERRITORYID,
ORDERDATE, REQUIREDDATE, SHIPPEDDATE,
SHIPVIA, FREIGHT, SHIPNAME,
SHIPADDRESS, SHIPCITY, SHIPREGION,
SHIPPOSTALCODE, SHIPCOUNTRY
```

The `orderdetails` table has these columns:

```
ORDERID, PRODUCTID, UNITPRICE, QUANTITY, DISCOUNT
```

And the `customers` table has these columns:

```
CUSTOMERID, COMPANYNAME, CONTACTNAME,
CONTACTTITLE, ADDRESS, CITY, REGION, 
POSTALCODE, COUNTRY, PHONE, FAX
```

I have to do three queries:

**1** List of orders with a higher total amount (unitprice * quantity * (1 - discount)) provided that the total amount is greater than 10000

I did it like this:

```
SELECT orderid  
FROM orders  
JOIN orderdetails USING (orderid)
GROUP BY orderid
HAVING SUM (unitprice * quantity * (1 - discount)) > 10000;
```

**2** Order with the highest total amount (including discount)

I did it like this:

```
SELECT MAX (orderid),
       SUM (unitprice * quantity * (1 - discount)) as price
FROM orders  
JOIN orderdetails USING (orderid)
ORDER BY price DESC;
```

**3** show the customerid and the freight (transport) of the customers who have spent more than 2000 freight on all their orders

I have not been able to do this

```
SELECT customerid,freight
FROM customers  
JOIN orders USING (customerid)
HAVING Count (freight) > 2000;
```

I want to know if I did #1 and #2 correctly or is there a better way to do it and how can I solve #3.

Thank you very much to all.

Comment: and where is your problem,  they are fine

Comment: the third gives me an error:  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error en la línea: 167, columna: 8

Comment: the last needs a group by and freight in the select an aggregation function

Comment: I did what you told me, but I think I have it wrong.
Because in this way it is checking all the "freights" that are greater than 2000 (the table comes out empty)

Comment: I need you to add the total freight costs of each customerid and then compare if they are greater than 2000

Comment: then you need to sum the Freight not count them, it is hard to guess with out data and a wanted result

Comment: i tried this ,but the result is weird

SELECT customerid,freight 
FROM customers  JOIN orders  USING  (customerid)JOIN orderdetails USING (orderid)
HAVING SUM  (freight)>2000 
GROUP BY customerid,freight  ;

Comment: no you can't group by freight also you don't need order_details

Comment: I have removed what he told me, but it gives me an error.
sorry

SELECT customerid,freight FROM customers JOIN orders USING (customerid)
 HAVING SUM (freight)>2000;

Comment: it must be like this https://dbfiddle.uk/HN-4Lml6

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `customers` table (since the `orders` table contains both `freight` and `customerid`) and need to have a `GROUP BY` clause and aggregate the `freight` column in the `SELECT` clause (and probably want to use `SUM` rather than `COUNT` but you haven't provided any sample data so it is difficult to tell):

```sql
SELECT customerid,
       SUM(freight)
FROM   orders
GROUP BY
       customerid
HAVING SUM(freight) > 2000;
```

Answer (score 0):

With Sample data like here:

```sql
WITH 
    orders (ORDERID, CUSTOMERID, EMPLOYEEID, TERRITORYID, ORDERDATE, REQUIREDDATE, SHIPPEDDATE, SHIPVIA, FREIGHT, SHIPNAME,
            SHIPADDRESS, SHIPCITY, SHIPREGION, SHIPPOSTALCODE, SHIPCOUNTRY) AS
        (
            Select 101, 1, 11, 'T1', DATE '2023-01-03', DATE '2023-01-24', DATE '2023-01-04', 'via A', 1500, 'A SHIP', 'Address 1', 'A CITY', 'A REGION', 'A ZIP', 'A COUNTRY' From Dual Union All
            Select 102, 1, 11, 'T1', DATE '2023-01-03', DATE '2023-01-24', DATE '2023-01-04', 'via A',  250, 'A SHIP', 'Address 1', 'A CITY', 'A REGION', 'A ZIP', 'A COUNTRY' From Dual Union All
            Select 103, 1, 11, 'T1', DATE '2023-01-03', DATE '2023-01-24', DATE '2023-01-04', 'via A',  500, 'A SHIP', 'Address 1', 'A CITY', 'A REGION', 'A ZIP', 'A COUNTRY' From Dual Union All
            Select 104, 2, 11, 'T1', DATE '2023-01-03', DATE '2023-01-24', DATE '2023-01-04', 'via A',  750, 'A SHIP', 'Address 1', 'A CITY', 'A REGION', 'A ZIP', 'A COUNTRY' From Dual Union All
            Select 105, 2, 11, 'T1', DATE '2023-01-03', DATE '2023-01-24', DATE '2023-01-04', 'via A',  950, 'A SHIP', 'Address 1', 'A CITY', 'A REGION', 'A ZIP', 'A COUNTRY' From Dual Union All
            Select 106, 2, 11, 'T1', DATE '2023-01-03', DATE '2023-01-24', DATE '2023-01-04', 'via A', 1250, 'A SHIP', 'Address 1', 'A CITY', 'A REGION', 'A ZIP', 'A COUNTRY' From Dual Union All
            Select 107, 3, 11, 'T1', DATE '2023-01-03', DATE '2023-01-24', DATE '2023-01-04', 'via A', 2500, 'A SHIP', 'Address 1', 'A CITY', 'A REGION', 'A ZIP', 'A COUNTRY' From Dual Union All
            Select 108, 4, 11, 'T1', DATE '2023-01-03', DATE '2023-01-24', DATE '2023-01-04', 'via A',  850, 'A SHIP', 'Address 1', 'A CITY', 'A REGION', 'A ZIP', 'A COUNTRY' From Dual Union All
            Select 109, 4, 11, 'T1', DATE '2023-01-03', DATE '2023-01-24', DATE '2023-01-04', 'via A',  950, 'A SHIP', 'Address 1', 'A CITY', 'A REGION', 'A ZIP', 'A COUNTRY' From Dual Union All
            Select 110, 5, 11, 'T1', DATE '2023-01-03', DATE '2023-01-24', DATE '2023-01-04', 'via A', 1150, 'A SHIP', 'Address 1', 'A CITY', 'A REGION', 'A ZIP', 'A COUNTRY' From Dual 
        ),
    details (ORDERID, PRODUCTID, UNITPRICE, QUANTITY, DISCOUNT) AS
        (
            Select 101, 1001, 700, 5, 0.1 From Dual Union All
            Select 101, 1002, 700, 5, 0.1 From Dual Union All
            Select 102, 1003, 800, 2, 0.1 From Dual Union All
            Select 102, 1004, 700, 2, 0.1 From Dual Union All
            Select 103, 1003, 900, 5, 0.3 From Dual Union All
            Select 103, 1004, 700, 6, 0.1 From Dual Union All
            Select 103, 1005, 700, 7, 0.1 From Dual Union All
            Select 104, 1001, 700, 1, 0.1 From Dual Union All
            Select 104, 1002, 900, 1, 0.2 From Dual Union All
            Select 105, 1002, 900, 3, 0.1 From Dual Union All
            Select 106, 1005, 700, 1, 0.1 From Dual Union All
            Select 107, 1003, 700, 7, 0.1 From Dual Union All
            Select 108, 1004, 700, 8, 0.2 From Dual Union All
            Select 109, 1003, 900, 8, 0.1 From Dual Union All
            Select 109, 1004, 900, 9, 0.3 From Dual Union All
            Select 110, 1005, 700, 9, 0.1 From Dual 
        ),
    customers(CUSTOMERID, COMPANYNAME, CONTACTNAME, CONTACTTITLE, ADDRESS, CITY, REGION, POSTALCODE, COUNTRY, FAX) AS
        (
            Select 1, 'A COMPANY', 'A CONTACT', 'A TITLE', 'Address 1', 'A CITY', 'A REGION', 'A ZIP', 'A COUNTRY', 'A FAX' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'A COMPANY', 'A CONTACT', 'A TITLE', 'Address 1', 'A CITY', 'A REGION', 'A ZIP', 'A COUNTRY', 'A FAX' From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 'A COMPANY', 'A CONTACT', 'A TITLE', 'Address 1', 'A CITY', 'A REGION', 'A ZIP', 'A COUNTRY', 'A FAX' From Dual Union All
            Select 4, 'A COMPANY', 'A CONTACT', 'A TITLE', 'Address 1', 'A CITY', 'A REGION', 'A ZIP', 'A COUNTRY', 'A FAX' From Dual Union All
            Select 5, 'A COMPANY', 'A CONTACT', 'A TITLE', 'Address 1', 'A CITY', 'A REGION', 'A ZIP', 'A COUNTRY', 'A FAX' From Dual Union All
            Select 6, 'A COMPANY', 'A CONTACT', 'A TITLE', 'Address 1', 'A CITY', 'A REGION', 'A ZIP', 'A COUNTRY', 'A FAX' From Dual 
        )
```

your 3 answers would be like below:

```sql
--  1. 
SELECT  ORDERID, Sum(UNITPRICE * QUANTITY * (1 - DISCOUNT)) "TOTAL_10K_PLUS"
FROM    orders  
JOIN    details  USING  (ORDERID)
GROUP BY ORDERID
HAVING SUM (UNITPRICE * QUANTITY * (1 - DISCOUNT)) > 10000;
/*
   ORDERID TOTAL_10K_PLUS
---------- --------------
       109          12150 
       103          11340
*/
```

```sql
--  2. Changed
SELECT ORDERID, TOTAL "HIGHEST_TOTAL"
FROM
    (   SELECT o.ORDERID,
               MAX(SUM(UNITPRICE * QUANTITY * (1 - DISCOUNT))) OVER(Partition By o.ORDERID) as TOTAL
        FROM   orders o  JOIN details d  ON  (d.ORDERID = o.ORDERID)
        GROUP BY o.ORDERID
        ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
    )
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
/*
   ORDERID HIGHEST_TOTAL
---------- -------------
       109         12150
*/
```

```sql
--  3. Changed
SELECT  CUSTOMERID, Sum(FREIGHT) "TOTAL_FREIGHT"
FROM    orders 
GROUP BY CUSTOMERID
HAVING  Sum(FREIGHT) > 2000;
/*
CUSTOMERID TOTAL_FREIGHT
---------- -------------
         1          2250 
         2          2950 
         3          2500 
*/
```